# nohup command stops after a while

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, watch, nohup

For an app i want an url to be visited every one second. to make this happen on my Google Cloud ubuntu server i run this command

`nohup watch -n 1 curl https://www.website.com/phpfile.php &`

after that i log out. This works fine for some time but after a while (not sure how long but i think some hours) it stops.

when i log back in to the server and i do a

`sudo ps -aux`

i still see the command but it doesn't seem run the .php file anymore(i conclude this by going to the url by hand and seeing that it didnt process). when looking at the performance of the server i don't see a problem there.

Am i doing something wrong, or is there maybe a better way to visit a url every one second without stopping?

Comment: Doesn't the site block the requests?

Comment: i don't think so. it is my own site. i don't see anything going wrong there. but good one, i will double check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use **nohup** to run background commands with SSH. nohup is designed for terminal sessions (terminals are the ancient CRTs that were connected using RS232).

Use **screen**, **tmux**, or similar programs that support detaching from and reattaching to a process. This will allow you to start a program, detach and the disconnect from SSH. Later you can reconnect with SSH, and then reattach to the program or programs.

[How To Use Linux Screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)

[Tmux Tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/tmux-tutorial-install-commands)

Comment: Thank you, i will try screen in stead of nohup and get back with the result. only thing i did for now is change the command nohup in to screen and it seems to work.

Comment: The above solution (using screen) does the trick! one follow up question; Can is use it multiple times? There is also another php script i want to acces but not every second. Can i use a second screen command for that one? Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Here is a link: https://superuser.com/a/349116/778550